# file and folder names containing spaces used as variable in a batchfile script

Tags: batch-file

I am writing code to reame and move *.mp3 files in a folder to the upper folder and add the folder name to the filename.  This code seems to work fine for folder names containing no spaces, but not otherwise.  What should I do?

WIndows 8 - bathfile
My code:

```
@ECHO OFF
for /D %%f in (*.) do call c:\users\sina\documents\renamemp3.bat "%%f"
```

this calls (renamemp3.bat):

```
cd %1
if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto end
for %%f in (*.mp3) do move %%f "..\%1(%%f).mp3"
cd ..
:end
```

Comment: Where should I add quotation marks?  move "%%f" "..\%1(%%f).mp3" didn't work!

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
for /D %%f in (*.) do call c:\users\sina\documents\renamemp3.bat "%%~ff"
```

this calls (renamemp3.bat):

```
@Echo off&Setlocal
cd /d "%~1"
if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto end
for %%f in (*.mp3) do move "%%f" "..\%~n1(%%~nxf).mp3"
cd ..
:end
```

You should take a look at for/arg variable modifiers `~` See `call /?` and `for /?`

Answer (score 0):

A couple of changes to the script's already provided

Main script:

```bat
@For /D %%A In (*) Do @Call "%UserProfile%\Documents\renamemp3.bat" "%%~fA"
```

renamemp3.bat

```bat
@Echo Off
If /I Not "%CD%"==%1 (PushD %1 2>Nul && (Set _=T)||Exit/B)
For %%A In (*.mp3) Do Move "%%A" "..\%~n1(%%~nA)%%~xA"
If "%_%"=="T" (Set "_=" & PopD)
GoTo :EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some recommendations that may help:

- Put quotation marks `""` around file and directory paths.
- Use the `~` modifier for `for` variables (like `%%~f`) and argument references (like `%~1`) when they might contain enclosing `""`.
- Avoid relative paths, espacially when multiple batch files are involved (e. g., run by `call`). Consider to use the `~f` modifier of `for` variables and argument references to return full absolute paths.
- For retrieving the pure base name and extension of a file or directory, always explicitly specify the `~n` and `~x` modifiers, respectively (or combined: `~nx`), of `for` variables or argument references.
- Consider to use [`pushd`](http://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html) and [`popd`](http://ss64.com/nt/popd.html) to temporarily change the working directory. (Nevertheless, if you insist in using `cd`, add the `/D` switch in order to change also the drive, if necessary.)
- Use the following [`set`](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) syntax: `set "VAR=Value"`; so the quotation marks are not part of the value. Surround the value by quotation marks only when it is read. (I know you did not use `set` in your code, but I want to mention this though.)

Having applied these rules to your code, it might look like this:

The main batch file:

```cmd
@echo off
for /D %%f in (*.) do call "c:\users\sina\documents\renamemp3.bat" "%%~ff"
```

The sub-script `renamemp3.bat`:

```cmd
rem // This replaces `cd /D "%~1"`:
pushd "%~1"
if ErrorLevel 1 goto end
for %%f in (*.mp3) do move "%%~f" "..\%~nx1(%%nxf).mp3"
rem // This replaces `cd ..`:
popd
:end
```

File `renamemp3.bat` can be simplified:

```cmd
rem /* The `&&` operator lets the following command (block) execute only in case
rem    the preceding one succeeded, hence its exit code equals zero: */
pushd "%~1" && (
    for %%f in (*.mp3) do move "%%~f" "..\%~nx1(%%nxf).mp3"
    popd
)
:end
```

Or even like this:

```cmd
rem // Using absolute paths directly prevents from having to change the working directory:
for %%f in ("%~1\*.mp3") do move "%%~f" "%~f1(%%nxf).mp3"
:end
```